# find consecutive operators in a string and replace previous operator with latest operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner and Working on a small project.Below is the issue where I am finding difficult to proceed.

1. One Array of operator is there `['+','-','*','/']`
2. One string Eg: `'42*+3';`

I need to find whenever there is consecutive operator in a string it should ignore previous operator and take the latest one.

Eg: `42*+3` should be `42+3`

I tried finding index of consecutive operator but how to replace the same in final string.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to match and capture an operator in a captured group, and repeat that capture group 1 or more times, then replace with that captured group. This way, consecutive operators will be replaced with only the last operator captured:

```js
const changeStr = str => str.replace(/([*/+-])+/g, '$1');

console.log(changeStr('5 +-* 6'));
console.log(changeStr('3 /- 4 ** 5'));
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine for every operator. But If we want to exclude - sign Eg: 5*-+5 should be 5+5 but 5*-5 should be same as 5*-5.  Means Negative sign shouldnt be ignored if it is last operator of a string.

Comment: If you don't want to replace `-`s when repeated with other operators, leave the `-` out of the character set. Then, consecutive, non-`-`s will be replaced with the last non-`-`.